# Custom File Type on Upload Menu

Tags: 2010, document-library, content-type

I have a custom Content type called Deliverable and it has been inherited from Document content type.

but when I go to document library and click on Upload Document button on the toolbar, I only See Upload Document and Upload Multiple document, but I cannot see the Upload Deliverable.

I expected to see Upload Deliverable too as it is inherited from document type.

is there any options page to make this item visible there?

Thanks

Regards

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add the new content type to the document library. The second part of this post gives more details - [Add a Document Content Type to a Document Library](http://techchucker.wordpress.com/2011/04/14/adding-document-content-types-sharepoint-2010/).

Comment: it adds the link to new document menu, but not to the Upload document menu